# Age problem of father and son

Tags: algebra-precalculus

A father's age is now five times that of his first born son.  Six year from now,  the old man's age will be only three times that his first born son. Find age of each.

Comment: This is nothing but a linear system whose unknowns are the ages of the two people.

Comment: Just use variable.  f = fathers age now.  s = sons age now.  f + 6 = fathers age in six years.  s + 6 = sons age in six years.  f = 5s.  f+6 = 3(s + 6).  Two linear equations with two unknowns.  Should be straightforward to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose present age of father is $x$ and present age of son is $y$. then according to question:

$$x=5y$$ and $$x+6=3(y+6)\implies x=3y+12$$.

Two equations two variables. I shall let you conclude now.

Answer (score 2):

Present ages,

Let son age = x

Then father = 5x

After 6 years,

Son age = x + 6

Father age = 5x + 6

According to the question,

5x + 6 = 3(x + 6)

5x + 6 = 3x + 18

5x - 3x = 18 - 6

2x = 12

x = 6

So present age of son x = 6

And father's 5x = 5 * 6 = 30.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Solve

$$F=5S$$
$$F+6=3(S+6)$$

Answer (score 1):

Solve:

$f = 5s$

$f + 6 = 3(s + 6)$

where $f$ and $s$ are father's and son's present ages respectively.